# ng-repeat removes ionic card

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a table with two columns: *Title* & *Content* Which I want to display in my Ionic Application with the **Card component**. My issue is when adding ng-repeat the card disappears? I am not entirely sure what happens to it but there is no indication or errors to why.

**Dashboard.html**

```
  <ion-view view-title="Dashboard" hide-back-button="true">
   <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content ng-controller="dashCtrl">      
 <div ng-repeat="val in districts">
 <div class="card">
             <div class="item item-divider">
                 I'm a Header in a Card!
             </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                APP{{val}}
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>   
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller.js**

```
  $scope.selectedDist=  function(data) {
              console.log(data);

                 $http.get("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/getFeed")
              .success(function(data) {

              var obj = data;
              var ar = [];
              angular.forEach(obj, function(index, element) {

              angular.forEach(index, function(indexN, elementN) {

                  console.log("========"+indexN.feedID);

                 ar.push({feedID: indexN.feedID, title: indexN.title, body: indexN.body});


                  $scope.districts = ar;
              }); 
              });


            })

          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("failure");
              })
```

Comment: does it work when you put it in the ng-repeat as opposed to on it?

Comment: What do you mean like in `<div class="item item-divider">`? @JoeLloyd

Comment: your angular code is a little strange, for starters I'd clean it up by creating a factory to handle the http request, that why you can set scope directly in the controller. [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000/blob/master/CordovaApp/CordovaApp/js/services.js) is a link to a bunch of services I wrote for an ionic app that handle http requests and return the array. You can then go check the controllers to see how I added the array to the scope and then to the html.

Comment: is the http request just returning a json object?

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. @JoeLloyd

Comment: Yes, From my Service. @JoeLloyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make a factory

```
.factory('YourStuff', function ($http) {
  return {
    get: function () {
        return $http.get('http://watevs')
    }
  };
})
```

## Mod your controller

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope, YourStuff) {
  YourStuff.get().success(function (response) {
    $scope.districts = response;
  })
})
```

This should set your districts to the $scope. you can then just loop through them with ng-repeat.

### Note

debug to see if the array comes in with `console.log(response);` and  `console.log(response[0]);`

Comment: happy to help. If you would like to see how I build angular apps take a look at [this](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight) repository. It shows you how to make each part of your site its own module. Good luck